# loading an external HTML file with ajax which has a FLASH app embedded

Tags: html, flash, embedding

I need to load contents of an external html document through AJAX. The problem is the external page has some Flash application embedded. 
Now I need to show this html with the embedded flash in my own webpage...
Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this question not well explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself...
this works fine for me:

```
 <div align="center" id="flexDiv">
    <p>
      <object id="external" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://alimsyed.com">
      </object>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, but I see no ajax call in this answer. No swf file either.